# Timer based execution

Tags: java, timer

I have to check whether a piece of code (e.g. call a third party web service) completes its execution within given time period. If output of the executing code does not comes in given time, execution should break and a default value should be passed to called object.

How to do it in java?

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you need two Threads.

The first thread is to execute the service call and the second thread should be scheduled to interrupt the first.

First Thread:

```
public class ServiceCall implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
       serviceClient.callOperation();
    }

}
```

Second Thread:

```
public class Interruptor implements Runnable {


public Interruptor(Future<?> future) {
serviceCallFuture = future;
}


private Future<?> serviceCallFuture;

public void run() {
serviceCallFuture.cancel(false);
}


}
```

Now the main logic:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
Future<?> future = executor.submit(new ServiceCall());
// Schedule interruptor to cancel the thread after 10 seconds
executor.schedule(new Interruptor(future), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```